# How to pass struct parameter to test function by using [TestCase] or [TestCaseSource] in NUNIT

Tags: c#, tdd, nunit

I practice TDD nowadays. 
I wanna simplify my poor test function by using [TestCase] or [TestCaseSource] attribute. please help me. this is my funcion now

```
    [Test]
    public void GetLength_TEST_1()
    {
        double output = Program.GetLength(new Point { x = 1, y = 2 }, new Point { x = 7, y = 8 });

        output *= 1000;
        output = Math.Truncate(output);
        output /= 1000;

        Assert.AreEqual(8.485, output);            
    }

    [Test]
    public void GetLength_TEST_2()
    {
        double output = Program.GetLength(new Point { x = 2, y = 7 }, new Point { x = -8, y = -6 });

        output *= 1000;
        output = Math.Truncate(output);
        output /= 1000;

        Assert.AreEqual(16.401, output);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute.

Note the same test method should exercise both test case.

Something like below.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClass
{
    public class PointTestCase
    {
        public string TestName { get; private set; }
        public Point P1 { get; set; }
        public Point P2 { get; set; }
        public double Result { get; set; } 

        public PointTestCase(Point p1, Point p2, double result)
        {
            P1 = p1;
            P2 = p2;
            Result = result;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return TestName;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PointTestCase> PointTestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new PointTestCase(new Point { x = 1, y = 2 }, new Point { x = 7, y = 8 }, 8);
            yield return new PointTestCase(new Point { x = 2, y = 7 }, new Point { x = -8, y = -6 }, -12);
        }
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource("PointTestCases")]
    public void GetLength_TEST(PointTestCase pointTestCase)
    {
        double output = Program.GetLength(pointTestCase.P1, pointTestCase.P2);

        output *= 1000;
        output = Math.Truncate(output);
        output /= 1000;

        Assert.AreEqual(pointTestCase.Result, output);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static double GetLength(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        //some logic/calculation
        return p1.x * p2.y;
    }
}

public class Point
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}
```